# Publish a site in a subfolder with traefik and Next JS

Tags: javascript, next.js, traefik

I'm trying publish a website in a subfolder (exemple.com/sitename) usign Traefik.

The site is build with Next JS.

What is happening when I run deploy is that all script links in the builded site disregard the folder (sitename). For example, js script named `generatedfile.js` is being accessed by the link `example.com/generatedfile.js`, the corret way would be `example.com/sitename/generatedfile.js`

My traefik args:

```
-l traefik.frontend.rule="Host:example.com; PathPrefixStrip:/sitename" -l traefik.frontend.entryPoints="http, https" -l traefik.frontend.headers.SSLRedirect="true"
```

I had tried add basePath to my next.config.js, but when I do this, I only access de site in the link `exemple.com/sitename/sitename`

next.config.js:

```
module.exports = withFonts({
  basePath: '/sitename'
});
```

I'm using docker to deploy in AWS.

I've been trying to solve this all day, I don't even know what else to try to solve it.

Sorry for my english, it's not my first language.

Comment: What happens if you remove `PathPrefixStrip:/sitename"` ? It looks like it strips away the sitename you want in there.

Comment: @anatolhiman I've already tried this, it gives an error without this parameter.

I also tried to leave only ```/``` but in this case it always directed to the main site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PathPrefixStrip` means match the path and strip the matched string before forwarding the request to your application. Use `PathPrefix` instead.

Looks like you're using v1.x of Traefik. Here's the documentation explaining the difference better: https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v1.7/basics/

It's worth mentioning that if you have multiple routing rules, Traefik sorts them by their string length in a descending order and goes through them to match the incoming request. In other words, `/api` is matched before `/`.